# Scraping asp.net page with several / no subpages: yield in if-else statement

Tags: python, asp.net, web-scraping, scrapy, yield

Here is the file spyder.py:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_spider.items import JobsItem


class JobSpider(scrapy.Spider): 
    
    name = 'burzarada' 
    start_urls = ['https://burzarada.hzz.hr/Posloprimac_RadnaMjesta.aspx'] 
    download_delay = 1.5 

    def parse(self, response): 

        for href in response.css('div.NKZbox > div.KategorijeBox > a ::attr(href)').extract(): 

            eventTarget = href.replace("javascript:__doPostBack('", "").replace("','')", "")
            eventArgument = response.css('#__EVENTARGUMENT::attr(value)').extract()
            lastFocus = response.css('#__LASTFOCUS::attr(value)').extract()
            viewState = response.css('#__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)').extract()
            viewStateGenerator = response.css('#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR::attr(value)').extract()
            viewStateEncrypted = response.css('#__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED::attr(value)').extract()

            yield scrapy.FormRequest( 

                'https://burzarada.hzz.hr/Posloprimac_RadnaMjesta.aspx', 

                formdata = { 
                    '__EVENTTARGET': eventTarget, 
                    '__EVENTARGUMENT': eventArgument, 
                    '__LASTFOCUS': lastFocus, 
                    '__VIEWSTATE': viewState, 
                    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': viewStateGenerator,
                    '__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED': viewStateEncrypted,
                },

                callback=self.parse_category 
            )
            
            
    def parse_category(self, response): 
        
        href = response.xpath('//select[@id="ctl00_MainContent_ddlPageSize"]').extract()
       
        eventTarget = "ctl00$MainContent$ddlPageSize"
        eventArgument = response.css('#__EVENTARGUMENT::attr(value)').extract()
        lastFocus = response.css('#__LASTFOCUS::attr(value)').extract()
        viewState = response.css('#__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)').extract()
        viewStateGenerator = response.css('#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR::attr(value)').extract()
        viewStateEncrypted = response.css('#__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED::attr(value)').extract()
        pageSize = '75'
        sort = '0'

        yield scrapy.FormRequest( 

            'https://burzarada.hzz.hr/Posloprimac_RadnaMjesta.aspx', 

            formdata = { 
                '__EVENTTARGET': eventTarget, 
                '__EVENTARGUMENT': eventArgument, 
                '__LASTFOCUS': lastFocus, 
                '__VIEWSTATE': viewState, 
                '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': viewStateGenerator,
                '__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED': viewStateEncrypted,
                'ctl00$MainContent$ddlPageSize': pageSize,
                'ctl00$MainContent$ddlSort': sort,
            },

            callback=self.parse_multiple_pages 
        )
        
    
    def parse_multiple_pages(self, response):

        hrefs = response.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_gwSearch"]//tr[last()]//li/a/@href').extract()
        
        ##################################
        # Here is the part of problem

        if len(hrefs) != 0: # yield statement
            
            for href in hrefs:

                eventTarget = href.replace("javascript:__doPostBack('", "").replace("','')", "")
                eventArgument = response.css('#__EVENTARGUMENT::attr(value)').extract()
                lastFocus = response.css('#__LASTFOCUS::attr(value)').extract()
                viewState = response.css('#__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)').extract()
                viewStateGenerator = response.css('#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR::attr(value)').extract()
                viewStateEncrypted = response.css('#__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED::attr(value)').extract()
                pageSize = '75'
                sort = '0'

                print(eventTarget)

                yield scrapy.FormRequest( 

                    'https://burzarada.hzz.hr/Posloprimac_RadnaMjesta.aspx', 

                    formdata = { 
                        '__EVENTTARGET': eventTarget, 
                        '__EVENTARGUMENT': eventArgument, 
                        '__LASTFOCUS': lastFocus, 
                        '__VIEWSTATE': viewState, 
                        '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': viewStateGenerator,
                        '__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED': viewStateEncrypted,
                        'ctl00$MainContent$ddlPageSize': pageSize,
                        'ctl00$MainContent$ddlSort': sort,
                    },

                    callback=self.parse_links 
                    
                )
        
        else: # another yield

            for link in links:

                link = 'https://burzarada.hzz.hr/' + link

                yield scrapy.Request(url=link, callback=self.parse_job)
        ##########################################
    def parse_links(self, response):

        links = response.xpath('//a[@class="TitleLink"]/@href').extract()

        for link in links:

            link = 'https://burzarada.hzz.hr/' + link
            yield scrapy.Request(url=link, callback=self.parse_job)

    def parse_job(self, response):

        item = JobsItem()

        item['url'] = ''
        item['title'] = ''
        item['workplace'] = ''
        item['required_workers'] = ''
        item['type_of_employment'] = ''
        item['working_hours'] = ''
        item['mode_of_operation'] = ''
        item['accomodation'] = ''
        item['transportation_fee'] = ''
        item['start_date'] = ''
        item['end_date'] = ''
        item['education_level'] = ''
        item['work_experience'] = ''
        item['other_information'] = ''
        item['employer'] = ''
        item['contact'] = ''
        item['driving_test'] = ''

        yield item
```

You can see that the page structure is not very complicated.

Here is the link to the page I want to scrape.

https://burzarada.hzz.hr/Posloprimac_RadnaMjesta.aspx

There are 16 hyperlinks on the page, each of them posts requests to get different numbers of jobs in a list.

The first link has <10 items in it, the second one has >1000. The viewport scale of the job list is set as 25, so first link has no subpages, and second link has 10+ subpages.

I managed to change them to 75 so that I don't have to deal with many subpages. The problem comes to the next part.

The thing is, I cannot get any items on the first link(the one with no subpages). Scraping only starts with the second link(the one with 10+ subpages). I tried to follow the flow with several print()s in the code(deleted for brevity and clarity) and I found it never touches the else: part there!

If I try with only the first page(limiting the for loop to run only once in the function parse()), then it works OK.

I have been struggling over this for hours and I cannot find any helpful answer.

I guess this is because the first link has no subpages in it. if it had some, then I wouldn't have to add if-else there!

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have launched the code and it seems working in general.

> Scraping only starts with the second link

It actually tries to work with the 1st category. The problem is that `links` is not defined and spider fails. Exception - `NameError: name 'links' is not defined`. Scrapy may fail on parsing the page, but this doesn't stop the whole crawler, so Scrapy continues the work with pages, which have pagination.

You can also include pagination and sorting in the 1st request in spider. In this case you can simplify the spider by removing `parse_category`.

Also this selector

```
hrefs = response.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_gwSearch"]//tr[last()]//li/a/@href').extract()
```

could be much simpler:

```
hrefs = response.xpath('//ul[contains(@class, "pagination")]//a/@href').extract()
```

Taking everything mentioned the [code](https://pastebin.com/WYgVN4Vt) could be a bit simpler.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't get the result I wanted to. It still refuses to go other pages. It only go round and round in one page. Let me show you the code I am debugging. https://pastebin.com/1MT2VYYa

Comment: @Nikita If you add `print(f"""parse_multiple_pages, title - {response.xpath('//span[@id="ctl00_MainContent_lblResults"]//text()').extract()}""")` in the beginning of the function `parse_multiple_pages`, you'll see that you are reading the same page. You definitely have some error in `parse_category`. The code in the link to pastebin in my post is simplified, so it doesn't have `parse_category` and the error. A bit updated code with few comments https://pastebin.com/EVgNxsiQ

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. You saved the day!!!